# @login_required decorator in django 1.1 and Template_name

Tags: django, authentication, django-templates, decorator

I uses `@login_required` in my views.. and in the django book they tell i you don't want to use the default registration/login.html template you can pass en extra view argument template_name.

But i v tried :

```
@login_required(template_name='washtest/login.html')
```

but i have an error

> login_required() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'

So how can i pass my template_name to use for login in my app ? with this decorator ?

Thx for help

laurent

Answer (score 3):

The `template_name` can be set on a [login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login), not on a `login_required` decorator.

`login_required` uses URL set in [settings.LOGIN_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url). So you define a your view with that URL and custom template:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),
```

That way you'll have custom login template.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any template var in login_required...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

You could use permission decorator in urls.py and then check if user is logged in:

```
(r"^market/$", permission_required("CHANGE", "/accounts/denied/")(CreateMarketView.as_view()))
```

Comment: here in the django doc :If you'd prefer not to call the template registration/login.html, you can pass the template_name parameter via the extra arguments to the view in your URLconf. For example, this URLconf line would use myapp/login.html instead:

(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),

You can also specify the name of the GET field which contains the URL to redirect to after login by passing redirect_field_name to the view. By default, the field is called next.

Comment: so i think i can use template_name with decorator to.. i m wrong i think

Comment: I think you should change template and to leave all logic in old view

Answer (score 0):

try this django documentation

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required(redirect_field_name='my_redirect_field')
def my_view(request):
```

Comment: It doesn't answer OP's question